# INSERT with Dapper takes too long in SQL Azure

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, dapper

I've got an instance of an entity, with a one to many relationship (Items). I'm attempting to have this inserted into a SQL Azure instance via Dapper.

The item count is ~3.5k

```
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
  // (...) x inserted here, we want to insert the items next...
  connection.Execute(TSQL_InsertStatement, x.Items, transaction);
  transaction.Commit();
}
```

- Locally (vs a .\SQLEXPRESS), the execution takes ~300-500[ms]
- In Azure, the execution takes ~8[s]

I believe this action generates a ton of individual INSERTs and this might be a problem. I've tried refactoring this to a "manually-generated-sql" solution, which generated 4x INSERTS (1k, 1k, 1k, 500 rows), however the execution of this took over 2[s] locally.

- Is there a way to have this run faster with Dapper? Like a bulk insert maybe?
- Is there something I'm not aware of with SQL Azure? Like some hidden throttling?

Comment: Local versus the Internet may be the differnece

Comment: sql database and the app performing the inserts are located in the same azure region (dc)

Comment: run some test inserts in a loop and see,what are the wait stats

Comment: Search on TVP SQLdataRecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiple inserts within same transaction is generally bad idea in Azure SQL Database.

You should use batching to increase performance of insert queries see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-use-batching-to-improve-performance/ .
If it is possible, I would recommend table value parameters, bulk insert or multiple parametrized inserts. These scenarios are described in the referenced article.

Azure Sql Database also has JSON support so if your original source is array of JSON objects you might push entire JSON as text and parse it in SQL side using OPENJSON (there are still no evidence is this faster than other methods).